# How to differentiate between a tap and hold?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

In my game I have two types of gestures; a single tap and a hold. When I hold my finger on the screen it causes `touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` to be called where my tapped method is called also, so both gestures are being called. How can I avoid this problem? Do I have to use `UIGestureRecognizers` or is there a way to just use the built in cocos2d methods? I need these gestures to be called exclusively, not in combination with each other.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, BPMovementState) {
    kTouchUp,  //Finger is not on the screen
    kTouchDown //Finger is on the screen
};

 @implementation HelloWorldScene
{
    CCSprite *_hero;
    BPMovementState _touchState;
}

- (instancetype)init

    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return(nil);

    // Enable touch handling on scene node
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    _touchState = kTouchUp;

    return self;
}

- (void)fixedUpdate:(CCTime)delta{

     if(_touchState == kTouchDown){
         //_hero slide
         _hero.position = ccp(_hero.position.x + 1, _hero.position.y);
     }

}

-(void) touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    _touchState = kTouchDown;
   if(touch.tapCount == 1)
        [_hero jump]

}

- (void)touchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{


    _touchState = kTouchUp;

}
```

Comment: You can note time between touch begin and touch ended. After that you can customize the criteria for recognizing tap and hold.

Comment: Tap is a sign of friendship. Hold is a sign of love.

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved by following way.

Define a timer in header I.e touchTimer

In touchBegan start the timer

touchTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:delay target:self selector:@selector(touchHasBeenHeld:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

In case if the timer expires and selector -touchHasBeenHeld id invoked before touch been released . its hold event.
Here you also invalidate the timer.

Otherwise if -touchEnded is called and timer is still valid, its a touch event.
Again you invalidate the timer.

Answer (score 0):

I would stick with `UIGestureRecognizer` if you can. Apple’s gesture recognizers are tuned to feel familiar to users. If you create your own, your timing or thresholds might slightly different, and the gestures will feel weird to users who are accustomed to the system default ones. [Here](http://franzzle.wordpress.com/2013/03/23/adding-gesture-recognizers-in-cocos2d/) is a quick tutorial on adding `UIGestureRecognizer` to cocos2d projects.